# Set up Areas and routing in my .NET Core 3.1 site - All of my links are just text now. How can they become links again?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

EDIT 2: Similarly some labels are simply not showing. Like this label in my edit page is completely missing after moving my project to use Areas:

```
<label asp-for="Devices.DeviceId" class="control-label"></label>
```

EDIT: I have fixed a few of my links, but the one in the original post still baffles me. Any ideas?

Examples of some links that are working:

```
<div data-submit-url="@Url.Action("Index","Devices")">
    <text style="font-weight:500">Results Per Page</text>
    <br /> 
    @Html.DropDownList("PageNumber", Model.ResultsPerPageList, (String)ViewData["ResultsPerPage"], new { @class = "form-control ays-ignore", @id = "ddlPageNum", @style = "min-width: 120px; margin-right:10px" })
</div>
```

or

```
<a href="Devices/Details/@item.DeviceId">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeviceId)
</a>
```

But the example from my original question, even when I change it to be similar to these other ways that work, I have trouble figuring out why it has no action when clicked.

---

I have tried a number of solutions from SO and many other sites, but something so simple is not working for me. I got Areas and routing set up correctly, or so it seems. I can navigate to my views when I type in a URL. And SOME of my links work, but many of them are no longer links. I don't mean they are taking me to the wrong view/URL. I mean they are just text and not links/Buttons like they used to be.

Here is a simple example from one of my views:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-action="Index">Devices</a>
```

That used to take me to the Index page for the view I was in. Simple enough.

I tried this because in my shared _Layout page I have a link that works which is:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Core" asp-controller="Devices" asp-action="Index">Devices</a>
```

For some reason, this only displays the text "Devices" in my views. Many buttons on the page are the same way. They are buttons that can be clicked, but they do nothing.

I added the routing annotations to my controllers like this:

```
[Area("Core")]
public class DevicesController : Controller
{
```

And this is how I set up my routing in the Configure method of Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area}/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

My questions are why did this break all of my links/buttons actions and make then text/buttons with no click actions? And how can I fix them?

I also want to add an odd observation. The couple of buttons that do work have white text (same as they did before moving to use areas/routing). The many that do not work the text on the button changed to black.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was broken because I did not understand the concept of Tag Helpers. My View Folder originally had a file named _ViewImports.cshtml which has a special line of code that was making all of my asp tags on my links work properly.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

I had to create copies of this file and put them under the folder Area/[AreaName]/Views/ and all was right again. I don't care to admit how much time that took me to figure out.

If you have ever had problems with your shared layouts when using areas you will see a similar behavior. All of the shared layouts can be copied into each area instead of having one main shared layout for everything in the project.